# Pushforward of a vector

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, differential-topology

The push forward of vectors allows to transform the components of a vector $X$ to be pushed along a map $h:\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{N}$ between the manifolds $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$. This is done in a way, such that applied to a function $f$ on

$$ f: \mathcal{N} \to \mathbb{R} $$

the following equality holds

$$ X_* f = X \,(f \,\circ \, h) $$
where $X_*$ is the pushed vector along the map $h$ (notation is often $h_*X$).

As an example with one-dimensional manifolds take a chart ($\mathcal{M},x$) and on the other manifold ($\mathcal{N},y$) and define a vector $X = \cos(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$ and the map between the manifold in these charts as $y = h(x) = x^2$. My goal is to to calculate $X_* X_*^1$, or in words I want to apply the pushed vector to its own components. This is an expression used to calculate the second application of a vector to a function.
By definition of the push forward it can be found, that the pushed component is
$$ X_*^1 = \cfrac{\partial h}{\partial x} X^1 = 2x \cos(x)  \quad .$$
Recall, that the components of a vector are functions on the manifold. So I can apply the vector $X_*$ to the first component $X_*^1$. And since $X_*$ was pushed to $\mathcal{TN}$, it can be written in the basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ which yields
$$ X_* X_*^1 = X_*^i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} X_*^1 = 2x \cos(x) \frac{\partial \, 2x\cos(x)}{\partial y}$$

and if I include the definition of the partial symbol, the last term is
$$ \frac{\partial \, 2x\cos(x)}{\partial y} = \partial_1 
\left( 2x\cos(x) \,\circ\, y^{-1} \right) \quad .$$
That is strange, since I cannot derive the expression of "$x$ variables" with respepct to "$y$". Or do I just have to derive with respect to $x$, because this ?is? the first argument?

A possible solution to this simple example would be to invert the relation of $h$ and subsitute. This is not the solution I'm looking for, since in my real problem $h$ is a projection (or basically selects some components) and is therefore not invertible! I also know, that one can use the definition of the push forward and work with the original vector $X \in \mathcal{TM}$ and "move" the function $f$ by using $f \,\circ\, h$. However, in calculations some vector $X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} (f \,\circ\, h)$ always yields a chain rule, which could be avoided with the pushed vector. In fact, if one has to use the definition, what good is the pushed vector anyway!?

---

My real problem is the following: I have a dynamical system with a vector field $X$ on the mfd $\mathcal{M}$, where I have a global chart $(\mathcal{M},x)$. Also I got an "output equation" $y = h(x)$ in coordinates, which defines another manifold $\mathcal{N}$ and simultaneously a chart $(\mathcal{N},y)$ for this manifold.
The map $h$ is a selection of states, which are of interest to me. So it's not a diffeomorphism.
I now want to introduce new coordinates $(\mathcal{N},\xi)$ on $\mathcal{N}$. These are functions 
$$\xi : \mathcal{N} \to \mathbb{R}^p
$$
Now I need the second Lie-derivative of one component function $\xi^a$ along the vector field $X$.
Since the Lie-derivative of a function is just the application I write the thing I want as
$$ X_* X_* \xi^a = X_*^i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i} 
(X_*^j) \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j} (\xi^a)
+
X_*^i X_*^j 
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^i y^j } \xi^a
$$
by the product rule.
What I was trying to simplify by using this $X_*$ is the term
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} 
(X_*^j)$$
which is part of the first term.
To make my life easy, I shortened $h_* X =: X_*$, which in components I can calculate to be 
$$X_*^i = h_{*a}^{i} X^a = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x^a} (y^i \circ h) X^a$$. And the whole vector is 
$$ X_* = X_*^i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$$.
These components are so given in the $x$ chart and the above stated problems arise. The other way I can think of is using the above definition and keeping $(\xi \circ h)$ everywhere. But then I wonder why there is such a thing as push-forward, if I have to subsitute its definition all the time.

Comment: What do you mean by $X = \cos (x)$ and by $h(x) = x^2$?

Comment: I tried to clarify that: $X$ is a vector (forgot the basis vectors to the components) on the maifold $\mathcal{M}$ and $h$ is a map between the manifolds $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your notation: is $X_* f$ supposed to be a function on $\mathcal{M}$? Or on $\mathcal{N}$? Judging by the fact that you want $X_* = h_*X$ in the more usual notation, I assume the latter, in which case you want
$$X_*f(y) = X[f\circ h]\left(h^{-1}(y)\right).$$

This gives you, in your example,
$$X_*^1(y) = 2\sqrt{y}\cos(\sqrt{y}),$$
and now you can proceed with your calculation:
\begin{align*}
X_*^1 \circ h &= 2x\cos x\\
X(X_*^1\circ h) &= (\cos x)(2\cos x - 2x\sin x)\\
(X_*X_*^1)(y) &= \left(\cos \sqrt{y}\right)\left(2\cos\sqrt{y} - 2\sqrt{y}\sin\sqrt{y}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: As already stated in the question: This is not the solution I'm looking for, since in my real problem h is a projection (or basically selects some components) and is therefore not invertible!

Comment: @mike you will need to further explain what you mean by $X_*$, then, as currently it doesn't make sense / is ill-defined. $X(f\circ h)$ is a function $\mathcal{M}\to \mathbb{R}$, not $\mathcal{N}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Put differently, what do you expect to get if you evaluate $X_*f$ at a point that is not in the image of $f$? A point where the preimage contains multiple points on $\mathcal{M}$?

You want to treat $X_*f$ as a function on $\mathcal{N}$, which only makes sense if $h$ is a diffeomorphishm.

Comment: I think I got hung up on my own example. I tried to explain where this problem arises, rather than focusing on the detail, after the line.
To your question: I'd take $X_* f$ as a function on $\mathcal{N}$, yeah, since I apply a vector from $\mathcal{T}\mathcal{N}$ to a function on the mfd.

Comment: After re-reading your solution, I assume the pushforwarded vector is only of use, if the map I'm pushing along is diffeomorphic?! Therefore, if it is, I can do, what you proposed, otherwise I have to live with the functions on $\mathcal{M}$, right?